# Single lever faucet shuts off by itself

Tags: kitchens, faucet

Single lever kitchen faucet will not remain open at slow flow rates. Lever moves by itself to “off”. Valve remains open at high flow rates. What is likely to be the problem?

Comment: Depending on how "low" the rate is where this happens, it might be *a feature* to prevent inadvertent dripping from failure to close it all the way. Specific make and model of the faucet would help get an actual answer, probably.

Comment: Those do exist, do you have one, show us

Answer (score 1):

I observed similar behavior after replacing the cartridge in the Price-Pfister Model 34 Single Control Kitchen Faucet in our kitchen sink.

In this faucet, the cartridge is mounted from above, downward into the faucet body. The cartridge is held in place by a brass retainer ring, which screws into fine threading on the interior face of the faucet body. A little tightening of the retainer ring solved the turns-itself-off problem.